# Resize iframe height according to its content height

Tags: jquery, html, css

how to resize iframe according to its content

here is my html code

```
<body>
<iframe id="test" src="http://www.bbc.co.uk/urdu/"></iframe>
</body>
```

and this is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        stretchHeight();
    }, 5000);

    function stretchHeight() {
        $("#test").height($("#test").contents().find("html").height());
    }
});
```

I tried without interval but not worked at that time too
so, please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you cannot access html (the content) inside an iframe. You will get permission issues.

Comment: simple answer, you cannot for cross domain iframe

Comment: can i know the height of scrollbar

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uMy3a/

Comment: What you're trying to do is possible (by using the javascript `postMessage` method) but only if you have access to the site you are targeting within the iframe.

Comment: how it's possible can you give me an example? please

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access the html in an iframe that is cross domain as this would be a security risk. Widths and Heights need to be manually defined.

HTH